# Syntax error in simple Insert Query

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm trying to create some basic insert query in PHP and it keeps trowing me an error but i really don't know why , can any you guys please see if there is anything wrong ?

```
    mysql_query("
INSERT INTO itens (nome, data, cliente, link, desc, img) VALUES ($nome,$data,$cliente,$link,$desc,$img)
") or die(mysql_error());
```

**Update**

Pulled from deleted answer of the OP, the code is now:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO itens (nome, data, cliente, link, `desc`, img) 
VALUES ($nome,$data,$cliente,$link,$desc,$img)") or die(mysql_error());
```

And the error is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'kl,j)' at line 2
```

The kl and j are the last two things i insert in the form.

Comment: Is the table's name really `itens` or `items`?

Comment: Never say "It gives an error".  Always say "It gives *this* error" and then paste the actual error.

Comment: Sorry the error is : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, img) VALUES (s,2012-12-18,(nome, data, cliente, link, desc, img),http://ww' at line 1

Comment: It's itens , its portuguese

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I know , after i put this to work i will secure it more, thanks

Comment: @user1555009 - Have you tried `("$nome","$data","$cliente","$link","$desc","$img")` instead of `($nome,$data,$cliente,$link,$desc,$img)`??

Comment: Your variables are strings, but you're not putting quotes around each value; see my answer as well.

Answer (score 7):

`DESC` is a MySQL Reserved Keyword, You should escaped it with `backtick`, ex

```
INSERT INTO itens (nome, data, cliente, link, `desc`, img) 
VALUES ($nome,$data,$cliente,$link,$desc,$img)
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

you're query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please take time to read the article below on how to prevent from it,

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Is it common practice to escape all column names?

Comment: @Sharlike nope, only those who are Reserved keywords must be escaped.

Comment: I changed the name of the column and now it shows me this error :
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'name,2012-12-25,Client,link,desc,link)' at line 1

Comment: is `name` present in your table. can you please post the result of the statement in your question `DESC itens`?

Comment: name is just what i wrote in the form

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost - **Escape, Escape, Escape** OR **Learn PDO / mysqli and prepared statements**.

Second - know what the [reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) are that can't be used for column names; those have to be escaped using backticks.

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO itens (nome, data, cliente, link, `desc`, img) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');", 
    mysql_real_escape_string($nome),
    mysql_real_escape_string($data),
    mysql_real_escape_string($cliente),
    mysql_real_escape_string($link),
    mysql_real_escape_string($desc),
    mysql_real_escape_string($img)
);

mysql_query($sql);
```

Third - I think you made a typo in the table name (`itens` vs `items`).

Comment: hey jack, `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't fully protect from `SQL Injection`. [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/5741264#5741264)

Comment: @JW. Hence the quotes around each escaped string. Please read properly.

Comment: how about number? will it protect from injection. I read it properly.

Comment: @Jw I don't see a number anywhere in the query.

Comment: yes, but that's not the point. The point is `mysql_real_escape_string` has a limitation on protecting you from the injection like numbers (*which is on the other case*).

Comment: @JW. Yes, *if* you don't put quotes around the argument after escaping it. Basically, even if the column is an `INT` I will still write `'123'` (if I were to use `mysql_query()` of course). Maybe I would use `%d` format specifier in `sprintf()` as an alternative.

Comment: Using `mysql_real_escape_string()` safely **requires** that one first correctly set the connection character set with `mysql_set_charset()`.  Furthermore, one must be careful to ensure either that the SQL mode does not include `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` or that literals are not quoted using in double-quote `"` characters.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string for more info.